# How to create power bi template

Tags: powerbi

How to create power bi template for different data sources(Ms SQL server,xlsx,csv,...).I mean I want to create one report(template) that give me the ability to upload different data sources and automatically rebuild my charts and formats in a new dynamic dashboard.

Comment: Do you mean you have the _same_ data in a bunch of different 'formats' (eg sql server, csv, xlsx etc) or you have a range of different data in different formats - eg you've got sales data in a sql db, staff hours in a csv format, budgets in spreadsheets?

Comment: Yes,I have a range of different data in different formats, and i need to create template in power bi. How can i use sql code like parameter?

Comment: It's incredibly easy to import data from a whole range of sources in PowerBI using the built in Power Query functionality. Perhaps if you gave some examples of what data you are trying to load and what you've tried we could help more?

Comment: Thank you very much for your help, I know how to create query in power bi from different sources, but i can't make a parameter using sql code. I don't have examples, i just created a file in pbit format